# is it possible to develop and deploy application to the SAP-Fiori Launchpad

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to develop some application for SAP Fiori with the OpenUI5, but I don't have acces to the SAP yet. So, my Question is:

Is it possible to develop application with OpenUI5 and deploy it to the SAP Fiori Launchpad after I get my access for it.

Comment: Where do you want to deploy the application is something you need to check. If you wish to deploy to the SAP abap system, you will need gateway components for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to complate below steps for registering your custom app to launchpad.

1. Upload your app as BSP application with **/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD** report.
2. Create new launchpad role in **LPD_CUST** t-code.
3. Add your app to this role with custom alias.
4. Create a new semantic object in /UI2/SEMOBJ t-code.
5. Create tile in Fiori Launchpad at http://yourserver/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/arsrvc_upb_admn/main.html
6. Create role in PFCG t-code for Fiori Launchpad Catalogs in menu tab.

More details are in this blog [post](https://pravin517.wordpress.com/2018/02/15/deploy-sapui5-application-into-fiori-launchpad/).

Not forget UI5 has multiple version, if you make your development with newer one, you cannot run it on old versions.

If you haven't got any SAP instance, you can install your own [ABAP trial system](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/04/sap-as-abap-751-sp02-developer-edition-to-download/) with WebIDE.